# MudNavGroup - change Title style

Tags: blazor-server-side, mudblazor

I want chage style ONLY of **Title** in **MudNavGroup**

`

```
<MudNavGroup Title="@item.Group.GroupName" Expanded="true"
                 Style="background-color:aqua; font-size:medium">
```

`

this code don't set style ONLY  **Title**
It change ALL style - Title-style and internal **MudNavLink** style
Please! help!

I try insert style

`

```
<MudNavGroup Title="@item.Group.GroupName" Expanded="true"
                 Style="background-color:aqua; font-size:medium">
```

`

but it change Title-style and internal MudNavLink-s styles.
But how change ONLY Title-style?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Style (note capital S) which overrides the mudblazor default style, you could maybe use lowercase s in style or use a class on the tag and use !important in css to force override for the specifics if it does not. Otherwise there are much more complex methods to access mudblazor's css through browser dev tools and changing and saving mudblazor css changes.